# API send photo to telegram bot by URL

Tags: api, telegram, telegram-bot

hi I want to send a photo by `telegram API` to my bot and I must use API URL to send and can not use library.

I tried:

```
token = " "
chat_id = " "
pic = ("C:\\Windows\\pic\\hello.jpg")

url = requests.post("https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendPhoto?chat_id="+chat_id+"&photo="+pic)

print(url)
```

And result:

```
{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong HTTP URL specified"}
```

Comment: it works for me, what exactly is your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Firstly**, It is `sendPhoto` not `sendphoto`.

Here is the [link for docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendphoto) for your reference.

Notice that you are giving the url for post requets as:
`https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendphoto?chat_id="+chat_id+"&photo="+pic`  **but it actually should be** `https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token+"/sendPhoto?chat_id="+chat_id+"&photo="+pic`

---

**Secondly**, you are trying to send a locally hosted image. Its a bit different to send locally hosted images than to send the URLs for online images.

You have to send the image file as a dictionary along with the post request like this:

```py
import requests

img = open(your/local/image, 'rb')
TOKEN = 
CHAT_ID = 

url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{TOKEN}/sendPhoto?chat_id={CHAT_ID}'


print(requests.post(url, files={'photo': img}))
```

Output:

`<Response [200]>`

---

Comment: I update my ask and improve that please cheack agian tnx

Comment: I have updated the answer, have a look. You should be using `sendPhoto` and passing the locally hosted image as a dict in post request.

Comment: Bro i exactly copy your code to my project but again got <Response [400]> i don't know why

Comment: my code works just fine, make sure you are passing **your local image** in `img` as `img = open("C:\\Windows\\pic\\hello.jpg", 'rb')` and set `url` as `url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+TOKEN+"/sendPhoto?chat_id="+CHAT_ID")` if you dont want to use *f-strings* like I did in the answer.
`

Comment: BRO VERY THX UR CODE WORKED , TNX

Comment: How can we send caption along with photo